# Error when export to CAD file

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, export, autocad

I'm using ArcGis 10.0. While output is faulty cad file

```
public static void *convertGdb2Cad*(IFeatureClass fromFile, string toFile)
       {


        Geoprocessor GP = new Geoprocessor();
        ESRI.ArcGIS.ConversionTools.ExportCAD tool = new
             ESRI.ArcGIS.ConversionTools.ExportCAD();
        //tool.in_features = "d:/lzx/data/road/test.gdb/line1";
        //tool.Output_File = "d:/lzx/data/cadfile1.dwg";
        tool.in_features = fromFile; // this OK
        tool.Output_File = toFile; // this OK
        tool.Output_Type = "DWG_R2007";
        GP.Execute(tool, null); //**Errors here when run** *Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.*
         //MessageBox.Show("ok");
```

}

How to fix this

Comment: That should be IGeoprocessor GP. SEE http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IGeoProcessor_Interface/002n000000tp000000/ there is a big difference between an interface and a class. The IGeoprocessor.Execute method works for me but expects a string and variant array see example http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/d/0001000001v9000000.htm

Comment: This [link](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=159&f=1707&t=247369) has a similar problem. There solution is was "In ArcEngine there is a license object control that I had to add to my form. " - see post dated Jun 10, 2008. It may be helpful.

Comment: I still have'nt solved this problem

Answer (score 1):

This is a snippet from one of my working programs that exports the result to CAD:

```
Dim vGP As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geoprocessing.IGeoProcessor2 = New ESRI.ArcGIS.Geoprocessing.GeoProcessor()
Dim Params As ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem.IVariantArray = New ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem.VarArray()
Params.Add(vScratchWS.PathName & "\Grid;" & vScratchWS.PathName & "\ac1")
Params.Add("DXF_R2000")
Params.Add(gInFolder & "\" & OutName.Text)

vGP.Execute("ExportCAD_conversion", Params, Nothing)
```

Translated into C# and using your variables:

```
ESRI.ArcGIS.Geoprocessing.IGeoProcessor2 vGP = (ESRI.ArcGIS.Geoprocessing.IGeoProcessor2) New ESRI.ArcGIS.Geoprocessing.GeoProcessor();
ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem.IVariantArray Params = New ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem.VarArray();
Params.Add(fromFile);
Params.Add("DWG_R2007");
Params.Add(toFile);
vGP.Execute("ExportCAD_conversion", Params, null);
```

Creating the tool directly should still work but the newer method (IGeoprocessor2) just uses the string for the tool name (same as arcpy) and the parameters in order.

Comment: Sorry, I have a little confusion:
///
public static void convertGdb2Cad(IFeatureClass fromFile, string toFile)
///
I tried but did not get.

Comment: I think the root problem is the first parameter is of type IFeatureClass not String. Try using (fromFile as IDataset).Name in your conversion: tool.in_features = (fromFile as IDataset).Name;

Comment: I'm using Database in ArcSDE
 
(fromFile as IDataset).Name //name = GISSERVER.SDE.Class1

but it not working

Comment: It's SDE data... try one SDE feature class in model builder then export to script to see the python syntax. I think you need "ConnectionName.sde\\GISSERVER.SDE.CLS1" which shouldn't be too difficult. Or set your gp.workspace to SDE. For non-sde use tool.in_features = (fromFile as IDataset).Workspace.PathName + "\\" + (fromFile as IDataset).Name; to get the FULL path if your gp.workspace is not set.

Comment: My database Locations is:Database Connections\GISSERVER.SDE\GISSERVER.SDE.Class1
But it's not working

Comment: Is it working in python? Can you please post your current code. SDE requires credentials, if they're not saved with the connection it will jump straight to "" and "" for username and password which will be rejected by SDE... in a lot of respects it would be better to convert to a shapefile first and then try exporting to CAD.